# How to use sklearn pre-processors

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

i have a data set with three columns, i want to apply svm machine learning algorithm, but i dont know what wrong in my code

i wrote this code

```
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
attack_data = pd.DataFrame(attack_data, columns = ['payload', 'label', 'attack_type'])
tf_train_data = pd.concat([attack_data['payload'], attack_data['attack_type']])
trained_tf_idf_transformer = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(tf_train_data)
attack_data['tf_idf_payload'] = trained_tf_idf_transformer.transform(attack_data['payload'])
attack_data['tf_idf_attack_type'] = trained_tf_idf_transformer.transform(attack_data['attack_type'])
data_for_model = attack_data[['tf_idf_payload', 'tf_idf_attack_type', 'label']]
x = data_for_model[['tf_idf_payload', 'tf_idf_attack_type']].as_matrix()
y = data_for_model['label'].as_matrix()
with open ("x_result.pkl",'wb') as handls:
        p.dump(trained_tf_idf_transformer,handls)
```

this error arise :
  attack_data['tf_idf_payload'] = trained_tf_idf_transformer.transform(attack_data['payload'])

File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 686, in **getattr**
    raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")

AttributeError: transform not found

Answer (score 1):

That's because fit_transform does not return the fit transformer, it returns the transformed data.

```
trained_tf_idf_transformer = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(tf_train_data)
attack_data['tf_idf_payload'] = trained_tf_idf_transformer.transform(attack_data['payload'])
```

is wrong and should be :

```
tf_train_data_transformed = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(tf_train_data)
attack_data['tf_idf_payload'] = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(attack_data['payload'])
```

See that you can use the same object tfidf_vectorizer to transform your other data (it has been updated when you trained it).

I cannot use your example as it is not reproducible and I'm a bit lazy to understand all the steps, but look at this one :

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

df_train = pd.DataFrame({'data': [1,2,3]})
df_validation = pd.DataFrame({'data': [1,2,3]})

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler_trained = scaler.fit_transform(df)
df_validation_transformed = scaler_trained.transform(df_validation)
```

raises the same error.

This code works :

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

df_train = pd.DataFrame({'data': [1,2,3]})
df_validation = pd.DataFrame({'data': [1,2,3]})

scaler = StandardScaler()
df_train_transformed = scaler.fit_transform(df)
df_validation_transformed = scaler.transform(df_validation)
```

You just need to follow the same logic.

Comment: i didn't get the solution and still have the same problem

Comment: @shorooq I have the feeling that you've finally got the solution seeing your next question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56942907/i-have-a-data-set-with-three-columns-and-am-trying-to-build-a-svm-model-from-the